# My code keeps returning -1 instead of actual answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def Add2NumbersTogether(x,y):

    try:

        s = str(x) + '.'
        y = float(s)
        print(y)
        return (x + y)
    except:
        return - 1


n = 90.09
v = 9

a = Add2NumbersTogether(n,v)
print(a)
```

Comment: Is there are reason you're trying to cast `x` to string and then re-assigning `y`?

Comment: no my friend helped me code it i dont understand why it wont work im very new to python , is this the error ? @sacul

Comment: Negative one absolutely is the expected answer for this code. Works exactly as coded.

Comment: The error is that you are trying to get some strangers on the internet to patch your friends code instead of taking the time to understand what it does.

Comment: this is the error that happens in try, except `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '90.09.'` this is because `x=90.09'` and `s='90.09.'` and when you do `float('90.09.')` it fails as there is an extra `.` which you have added for some reason.

Comment: Why do you have the `y` parameter? What it is for? In your code you simply discard that value...

Comment: Catching and ignoring every possible exception is a great way to hide errors.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to convert `90.09.` to a float. This occurs because statement `s = str(x) + '.'` converts 90.09 into a string and appends `.` to it. Since there are two `.` in this string, when we attempt to convert it to a float an exception is thrown, caught, and handled by returning -1.

For the record this is why catching *all* exceptions is a bad idea. You should only catch the exceptions you *expect and can handle*.

Comment: Aside from the extremely confusing punctuation, this is correct.

Comment: where is this 2nd dot i cant see it for some reason @Mo H.

Comment: `s = str(x) + '.'` appends a `.` to x as var s, you then try and conver s to a float..

Comment: shall is remove that dot then @MoH.

Comment: @EuanMason I have no idea what it is you are trying to accomplish by doing the conversion in the first place, all I can tell you is why you are getting the -1.

Comment: @MoH. I think you should add _"`s = str(x) + '.'` appends an extra `.` to the string representation of `x`"_ (or something like that) to your answer for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add to numbers, example code could be:

```
def Add2NumbersTogether(x,y):
    return x+y
```

There is no need to convert x and y into string type.

When you convert data to string type (i.e., `str`), you are actually appending two strings.

Comment: I will point out while this is the correct way to do this, it does not answer OPs question, which was WHY he was getting -1, not how to properly write an addition function

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that by converting a variable which Python interprets as a float to string and adding it the string `.` you will create something that is in general not a number anymore and can't be converted back to float. The exception is thrown because of this. What could be unclear to you is that by passing the Python interpreter the variable

> v=90.09

it automatically stores it as a floating point number. This being said it is unclear to me why you would take such a route to sum two number entries.